# Positive distance between sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Let A and B be nonempty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $|a-b| > \delta$.

I can not seem to prove this.  I have tried many things and been given many hints with no luck.  Can someone show me how this one is done please? Thank you!

Comment: Homework?  Here's a hint, anyway: the distance is a continuous function, and $A$ and $B$ are compact.  Consider the infimum of $\{d(a,b)~|~ a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Comment: No not homework. A problem that I am trying to work through that I have had no luck with.  I have tried many things that all came out wrong.  I am trying to teach myself analysis and most of the hints have been topological stuff I don't understand.  I feel like there should be a way to write a contradiction proof with sequences but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

$A\times B$ (with product topology) is compact, $f\colon A\times B\to \mathbb R$, $(a,b)\mapsto |a-b|$ is continuous, hence the minimum is assumed at some $(a_0,b_0)$. Then $f(a_0,b_0)>0$ as otherwise we would have $a_0=b_0$. Let $\delta=\frac12 f(a_0,b_0)$.